# JavaEE 6 application using Wicket on GlassFish 4 @Resource annotation fail

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, glassfish

This simple Wicket page works perfect in GlassFish 3.1.2.2 server but does not work when deployed in GlassFish 4.0.
Very important to note that other pages not containing @Resource annotation work perfect.

```
public class IndexPage extends WebPage {

  // this EJB injection works as expected
  @EJB(name = AnyManager.NAME)
  AnyManager anyMgr;

  // this JNDI Resource is defined as java.util.Properties at JNDI/Custom Resources of GlassFish admin console
  // this resource can be looked up using normal InitialContext.doLookup() method
  @Resource(name = "anyResource")
  Properties config;

  public IndexPage(final PageParameters p) {
    super(p);
  }
}
```

It gives the following Exception:

```
Last cause: org.apache.wicket.proxy.ILazyInitProxy not found by org.glassfish.hk2.external.cglib [27]
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public hu.app.IndexPage(org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters)' and argument ''. An exception has been thrown during construction!
```

See the Stack trace (starting from the IndexPage constructor's first line):

```
Root cause:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.proxy.ILazyInitProxy not found by org.glassfish.hk2.external.cglib [27]
     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:384)
     at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
     at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory.createProxy(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:190)
     at org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEProxyFieldValueFactory.getCachedProxy(JavaEEProxyFieldValueFactory.java:149)
     at org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEProxyFieldValueFactory.getFieldValue(JavaEEProxyFieldValueFactory.java:79)
     at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.inject(Injector.java:111)
     at org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEComponentInjector.inject(JavaEEComponentInjector.java:68)
     at org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEComponentInjector.onInstantiation(JavaEEComponentInjector.java:74)
     at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:38)
     at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:34)
     at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.notify(ListenerCollection.java:80)
     at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.onInstantiation(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:33)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.(Component.java:683)
     at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.(MarkupContainer.java:121)
     at org.apache.wicket.Page.(Page.java:168)
     at org.apache.wicket.Page.(Page.java:132)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.(WebPage.java:76)
     at hu.app.IndexPage.(IndexPage.java:56)
```

After doing a lot of Google search I had an idea try to do the injection in one of my manager beans
and I defined a simple getter for it. See the following lines how it looks like:

```
@Local
public interface AnyManager extends EntityManager {
  public static final String NAME = "ejb/AnyManager";
  Properties getConfig();
}

@Stateless(name = AnyManager.NAME)
public class AnyManagerImpl extends AbstractEntityManager implements AnyManager {

  @Resource(name = "iOIRConfig")
  Properties config;

  @Override
  public Properties getConfig() {
    return config;
  }
}
```

And I have changed my Wicket Page like this:

```
public class IndexPage extends WebPage {

  @EJB(name = AnyManager.NAME)
  AnyManager anyMgr;

  // so I have commented out
  // @Resource(name = "anyResource")
  Properties config;

  public IndexPage(final PageParameters p) {
    super(p);

    // and get the value from one of my EJB manager class
    config = anyMgr.getConfig();
  }
}
```

And this works for me. I do not like this type of solution I am still looking for the real explanation and solution.
What could be changed in GlassFish 4 which causes this simptoms? I do not have this strange effect in GlassFish 3.

I have clean installs both for GlassFish 3 and GlassFish 4.

My application is an EAR application which contains an EJB.jar, WEBAPP.war and a lib/ folder with shared common jars.
Perhaps this is some kind of classloader issues because EJB and WebApp located in different folder? 
But why @EJB works and @Resource does not?

Perhaps it is a Java EE 7 implementation issue or simple bug in GlassFish 4?

Any help would be nice.